# Degeneracy Condition

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I understood that when plotting the feasible area there had to be an intersection with more than two lines.

In the case of:

$$\text{Max     } z=2x_1+x_2$$
S.T
$$
\begin{cases}
4x_1+3x_2\leq 12\\
4x_1+x_2 \leq 8\\
4x_1-x_2 \leq 8\\
x_1,x_2\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

[The plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4x%2B3y%3D12+and+4x%2By%3D8+and+4x-y%3D8+and+x+%3D0+and+y+%3D+0) is which mean that there is almost intersection of the there functions, is it still degeneracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: yes this LP admits degenerate solutions, e.g., $(x_1, x_2)=(2,0)$, since the constraints $4x_1+x_2 \leq 8, 4 x_1-x_2 \leq 8, x_2 \geq 0$ are all active at this point, and $3$ active constraints in a 2d space implies degeneracy.

Comment: But using simplex I get that a basic variable has a value of zero, so it is degenerate right?

Comment: Ah right, I missed the non-negativity constraints. Yes, $4x_1+x_2 \leq 8, 4 x_1-x_2 \leq 8, x_2 \geq 0$ are all active at $(x_1, x_2)=(2,0)$, so yes that point is degenerate.

Comment: But still there is no intersection of 3 or more lines

Comment: In your plot, don't $x=0, 4x+y=8, 4x-y=8$ intersect at the same point?